# How to properly Map and Search json records returns by API using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

The code below list json records from the ApI and is working great. Now I want to add search box so that I can search records as well.

When I access statues.json record below is how it looks

```
[{"id":3,"name":"Tony","Age":15,"gender":"Male"},
{"id":2,"name":"Michal","Age":19,"gender":"Male"},
{"id":1,"name":"Joy","Age":48,"gender":"Female"}]
```

So I have added the following code for the search where appropriate.

```
 this.filterRecord = this.filterRecord.bind(this);
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  filterRecord(record)
    {record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1 ||
    record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
    record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1}

 <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"
            id="searchdata"
            name="searchdata"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.searchdata}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
```

**Here is my problem**

When I now change the map function from

```
{this.state.statuses.map((status, i) => (
```

to

```
this.state.statuses.filter(this.filterRecord).map((status) => (
```

no result/records will displayed. I mean the displayed result list will just disappear. I think the issue is with the map function

**Here is the code**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Person,
  lookupProfile
} from 'sacota';

const avatarFallbackImage = 'https://mysite/avatar-placeholder.png';

export default class Profile extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

 this.filterRecord = this.filterRecord.bind(this);
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);


    this.state = {
      person: {
        name() {
          return 'ok';
        },
        avatarUrl() {
          return avatarFallbackImage;
        },
      },
      username: "",
      statuses: [],
      statusIndex: 0,
      isLoading: false,

      searchdata: "",

    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const { userSession } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      person: new Person(userSession.loadUserData().profile),
      username: userSession.loadUserData().username
    });
  }

  fetchData() {
    const { userSession } = this.props
    this.setState({ isLoading: true })
    if (this.isLocal()) {
      const options = { decrypt: false }
      userSession.getFile('statuses.json', options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            person: new Person(userSession.loadUserData().profile),
            username: userSession.loadUserData().username,
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses,
          })
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    } else {
      const username = this.props.match.params.username

      const options = { username: username, decrypt: false }
      userSession.getFile('statuses.json', options)
        .then((file) => {
          var statuses = JSON.parse(file || '[]')
          this.setState({
            statusIndex: statuses.length,
            statuses: statuses
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('could not fetch statuses')
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.setState({ isLoading: false })
        })
    }
  }

  isLocal() {
    return this.props.match.params.username ? false : true
  }


// Enable Search
 handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  }

  filterRecord(record)
    {record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1 ||
    record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
    record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) >
      -1}

  render() {
    const { handleSignOut, userSession } = this.props;
    const { person } = this.state;
    const { username } = this.state;

    return (
      !userSession.isSignInPending() && person ?
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
            {this.isLocal() &&
              <div className="new-status">
                <div className="col-md-12">

  <h3>Search stat.....</h3>

        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search by name, Age and gender"
            id="searchdata"
            name="searchdata"
            type="text"
            value={this.state.searchdata}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
                </div>
              </div>
            }
            <div className="col-md-12 statuses">
            {this.state.isLoading && <span>Loading...</span>}


{this.state.statuses.map((status, i) => (

              <div className="status" key={i}>
                {status.Age}  {status.gender} {status.name}
              </div>
            ))}

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div> : null
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.statuses.filter(this.filterRecord)` - have you tried using `this.state.statuses.filter((status) => this.filterRecord(status))` instead?

Comment: @Cr0w3 do you omit map function in that line of code

Comment: I was just referring to that filter function - you can use map after that just fine in case the filtering works. :)

Comment: I believe its because you don't have a return in your filter function.

Comment: @octobus is right. I didn't even see that considering the strange formatting here and being used to arrow functions ;)

Comment: @Cr0w3 Thanks for your efforts so far in trying to assist me. my head is filled up.  I hope this is what you mean but unfortunately it throws  unexpected error    `{this.state.statuses.filter((status) => this.filterRecord(status))
{status.Age}  {status.gender} 
}` can please give a full line of code

Comment: @octobus Thanks also for coming in. please where exactly in the line of code do I pass the return function. can you please give sample. hoping to hear from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not returning anything to your `array.filter`. Simply return your if statements and it should work.

```
filterRecord(record){
  return record.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) > -1 ||
  record.Age.indexOf(this.state.searchdata) > -1 ||
  record.gender.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.state.searchdata.toUpperCase()) > -1
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure code seems ok to me. But can you `console.log(this.state.searchData)` inside `render ` and also can you `console.log(event)` in your `handleChange` function to see if it invokes @NancyMooree

Comment: Thanks alot. I will buy you a bottle of beer

Comment: please one more request @octobus. I needed to display a message incase if search record was not found

I have tried implementing the code below

`get info() {
    if ( this.state.statuses.length === 0) {
       return (<li>Search Records not Found.</li>);
    }
    return null;
}`


this is how I pass it in the render method but not working

`{this.info}`

any idea on what might be wrong

Comment: You are not calling the function you must use as `{this.info()}`

Comment: Thanks @octobus for your response. it still does not work. I think the problem lies in the filter as per this line of code  `filterthis.state.statuses.filter(this.filterRecord).map((status, i) => (`   should I add filter in the map and try something like  `this.state.statuses.filter.length === 0) { return (<li>Search Records not Found.</li>); } return null; }`  waiting for your response

Comment: Can you produce an example on codesandbox, so i can try and debug, this way is really complicated understand the problem. @NancyMooree